# Cast Dictionary<TKey, TValue> as Dictionary<TKey, TBaseValue>

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, dictionary, casting

Given:

```
class TKey {}
class TBaseValue {}
class TValue : TBaseValue {}
```

How can we cast

```
Dictionary<TKey, TValue>
```

As

```
Dictionary<TKey, TBaseValue>
```

And why can it not be done implicitly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` is not read-only, you can't use covariance here (indeed, the type is declared without the `out` or `in` that would allow co-/contra-variance).

To illustrate why this is the case, just consider what would happen once you've cast to `Dictionary<TKey, TBaseValue>`. You're still dealing with the original dictionary, which has values that are supposed to only be `TValue`. But cast that way, you could add some different sub-class of `TBaseValue` (or even `TBaseValue` itself), which would violate the rules of the original object's type.

Basically, this is C#'s way of preventing you from making a big mistake. :)